# Android Custom BaseAdapter getView not called

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

So, I have scoured the interwebs and I cannot find a solution for this based on other people's experiences, so I am posting this issue. (Please note that this is my 1st android app experience and I am debugging / updating an existing app.)

When I implement my custom NotesListAdapter (extends BaseAdapter) on the ListView, mListNotesView (mListNotesView.setAdapter(this)), and load the data into the ArrayList mNoteList, the getView function is not being called. Also, I found that mListNotesView.setBackgroundResource is not chaning the background of the control, either.  I have a similar implementation on a previous activity that works exactly correct. When I copied over the class and changed it to handle my ArrayList, it broke. I have getCount returning the ArrayList size(), which is not 0, and getItemId returns position. I have a feeling it may be my XML or my setup because it's acting like the ListView is not visible. I am perplexed. How do I get the ListView to show? Anything inside of the getView has not been reached so it may be buggy.

### ViewTicketOrderActivity (Some parts ommitted for size)

```
public class ViewTicketOrderActivity extends Activity {
    MySQLDatabase myDataBase;
    Ticket mTicket;
    public ArrayList<Notes> mNotes = new ArrayList<Notes>();
    String mErrorString;
    Button mAddUpdateButton;
    Button mAcceptButton;
    //Button mViewNotesButton;
    NotesListAdapter mNotesListAdapter;
    static final int ERROR_DIALOG = 0;
    static final int SUCCESS_DIALOG = 1;
    static final int COMPLETED_DIALOG = 2;
    static final int RESTART_DIALOG = 3;
    static final int LOADING = 0;
    static final int LOAD_ERROR = 1;
    static final int LOADED = 4;
    static final String TICKET_EXTRA = "ticket_extra";
    static final String TAG = "ViewTicketOrderActivity";
    private static final boolean gDebugLog = false;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewticketorder);
        Activity context = this;

        String theTitle = "Sundance Ticket Order";
        theTitle += (MySQLDatabase.TESTING == true) ? " (DEV SERVER)" : " (LIVE)";
        setTitle(theTitle);
        myDataBase = MySQLDatabase.getMySQLDatabase(this);
        if (gDebugLog)      {
            DebugLogger.logString(TAG, ".onCreate");
        }
        mNotesListAdapter = new NotesListAdapter(context, R.id.note_list);
        Log.d(this.toString(),this.mNotesListAdapter.toString());
    }
    private class NotesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ArrayList<Notes> mNoteList;
        private ListView mListNotesView;
        private Activity mActivity;
        int mState = LOADING;
        String mErrorMessage;

        private NotesListAdapter(Activity context, int listViewID) {
            mActivity = context;
            mNoteList = new ArrayList<Notes>();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mListNotesView = (ListView)context.findViewById(listViewID);
            mListNotesView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.emergency_red);
            mListNotesView.setAdapter(this);
            Log.d(mListNotesView.toString(), String.valueOf(mListNotesView.getCount()));
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //mListNotesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        void setLoading()
        {
            mState = LOADING;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        void setLoadError(String errorString)
        {
            mState = LOAD_ERROR;
            mErrorMessage = errorString;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        void setNoteList(ArrayList<Notes> inNotes)
        {
            mState = LOADED;
            mNoteList.clear();
            mNoteList.addAll(inNotes);

            Log.d("SetNoteList", "TRUE " + inNotes);
            //mNoteList = mNotes;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


        /**
         * Use the array index as a unique id.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
         */
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public int getCount(){
            if (mState == LOADED) {
                Log.d("getCount",String.valueOf(mNoteList.size()));
                return mNoteList.size();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            Log.d("getView",this.toString());
            if (mState == LOADED) {
                ViewHolder holder;
                // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there
                // is no need
                // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the
                // convertView supplied
                // by ListView is null.
                Notes note = this.getItem(position);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    /*if (ticket.emergency())
                    {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.emergency_ticket_list_item_opt,
                            null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket_list_item,
                                null);

                    }*/
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.noteslist_item,
                            null);
                    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two
                    // children views
                    // we want to bind data to.
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.noteText = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.text_note);
                    holder.dateText = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.text_note_date);
                    holder.createByText = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.text_note_by);
                    holder.createByIDText = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.text_note_by_id);


                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the
                    // TextView
                    // and the ImageView.
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
                holder.noteText.setText(note.note());
                holder.dateText.setText(note.date());
                holder.createByText.setText(note.createBy());
                holder.createByIDText.setText(note.employeeID());
                if(!mTicket.employeeID().equals(note.employeeID())){
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.solid_purple);
                }

            } else if (mState == LOADING ) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_view,
                            null);
                }
                TextView messageText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
                messageText.setText("Loading tickets");

            } else if (mState == LOAD_ERROR) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.load_error_view,
                            null);
                }
                TextView messageText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
                messageText.setText("Error loading tickets");
                String errorString = mErrorMessage != null ? mErrorMessage : "";
                TextView errorText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.errorText);
                errorText.setText(errorString);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView noteText;
            TextView dateText;
            TextView createByText;
            TextView createByIDText;
        }
        //@Override
        /*public int getCount() {
            *//*if (mState == LOADED) {
                *//*
            Log.d("getCount mState " + mState,String.valueOf(mNoteList.size())+", "+String.valueOf(mNotes.size()));
            return mNoteList.size();
            *//*} else {
                Log.d("getCount mState " + mState,"0");
                return 0;
            }*//*
        }*/
        @Override
        public Notes getItem(int position) {
            Log.d("getItem",mNoteList.get(position).toString());
            return mNoteList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType (int position) {
            int result = mState;
            Log.d("getItemId",String.valueOf(position));
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount ()
        {
            return 4;
        }

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null)
        {
            mTicket = (Ticket)extras.getSerializable(TICKET_EXTRA);
        }
        else
        {
            mTicket = new Ticket();
        }
        if (mTicket.emergency())
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.view_emergency_ticketorder);        
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.viewticketorder);       
        }

        if (gDebugLog)
        {
            DebugLogger.logString(TAG, ".onResume mTicket " + mTicket);
        }
        TicketCheckService.clearNotificationForNewTicket(mTicket);
        new GetTicketTask().execute();
        new GetNotesTask().execute();
        updateDisplayedTicket();

    }

    private void updateDisplayedTicket() {
        mAddUpdateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addUpdateButton);
        mAcceptButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.acceptButton);
        //mViewNotesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.viewNotesButton);

        String ticketStatus = myDataBase.getDescriptionStringForStatusString(mTicket.status());
        if(ticketStatus == "Job Rejected") {
            mAddUpdateButton.setText("Restart Job");
        } else {
            mAddUpdateButton.setText("Add Update");
        }
        if(ticketStatus == "Requested") {
            mAcceptButton.setText("Accept");
        } else if(ticketStatus != "Requested") {
            mAcceptButton.setText("Back");
        }
        //mViewNotesButton.setText(R.string.viewNotes);

        TextView idText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTicketID);

        idText.setText(mTicket.id());

        //TextView descriptionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDescription);

        //descriptionText.setText(mTicket.description());

        TextView titleText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        titleText.setText(mTicket.title());

        TextView storeIDText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStoreID);
        storeIDText.setText(mTicket.store());

        String formatPhone;
        TextView storePhoneText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStorePhone);
        if(mTicket.phoneNo().isEmpty()){
            formatPhone = "NO PHONE NO.";
        } else {
            storePhoneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStorePhone);
            formatPhone = mTicket.phoneNo().replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "($1)$2-$3");
            storePhoneText.setOnClickListener(new CallClickListener(mTicket.phoneNo()));
        }
        storePhoneText.setText(formatPhone);

        TextView categoryText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCategory);
        String categoryDescription = MySQLDatabase.getDescriptionStringForCategoryString(mTicket.category());
        categoryText.setText(categoryDescription);

        if(ticketStatus == "Completed Pending") {
            showDialog(COMPLETED_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    public void onClickAccept(View v) {
        try {
            boolean maint = myDataBase.getSystemMaintStatus();
            if(maint) {
                setLoadError("The phone app is down for maintenance.");
                return;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(mAcceptButton.getText() =="Accept") {
            mAddUpdateButton.setEnabled(false);
            mAcceptButton.setEnabled(false);
            new AcceptTicketTask().execute();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void onClickAddUpdate(View v) {
        try {
            boolean maint = myDataBase.getSystemMaintStatus();
            if(maint) {
                setLoadError("The phone app is down for maintenance.");
                return;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(mAddUpdateButton.getText() =="Add Update") {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, UpdateTicketActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(UpdateTicketActivity.TICKET_EXTRA, mTicket);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if(mAddUpdateButton.getText() =="Restart Job") {
            mAddUpdateButton.setEnabled(false);
            mAcceptButton.setEnabled(false);
            new RestartTicketTask().execute();
        }
    }

    private class AcceptTicketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> 
    {
         protected String doInBackground(Void... parent) {
             mErrorString = null;
             String result = null;
                String updateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(0));
            try {
                boolean success = myDataBase.updateTicket(mTicket.id(), mTicket.employeeID(), mTicket.description(), "1", updateTime, null);
                if (!success)
                {
                    result = "Could not update Ticket";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                result = "Could not update Ticket - " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return result;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String errorString) {
            if (null != errorString) {
                mErrorString = errorString;
                showDialog(ERROR_DIALOG);
            } else {
                showDialog(SUCCESS_DIALOG);
                mAcceptButton.setText("Back");
            }
            mAddUpdateButton.setEnabled(true);
            mAcceptButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
     }

    private class RestartTicketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> 
    {
         protected String doInBackground(Void... parent) {
             mErrorString = null;
             String result = null;
                String updateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(0));
            try {
                boolean success = myDataBase.updateTicket(mTicket.id(), mTicket.employeeID(), mTicket.description(), "7", updateTime, null);
                if (!success)
                {
                    result = "Could not update Ticket";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                result = "Could not update Ticket - " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             return result;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String errorString) 
 {
            if (null != errorString) {
                mErrorString = errorString;
                showDialog(ERROR_DIALOG);
            } else {
                showDialog(RESTART_DIALOG);
                mAcceptButton.setText("Done");
                mAddUpdateButton.setText("Add Update");
            }
            mAddUpdateButton.setEnabled(true);
            mAcceptButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
     }

    private class GetTicketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Ticket> 
    {
        String mError = null;
         protected Ticket doInBackground(Void... parent) {
             Ticket result = null;
            try {
                result = myDataBase.getTicketWithID(mTicket.id(), mTicket.employeeID());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                mError = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Ticket result) 
         {  
            if (null != result) {
                mTicket = result;

            } else {
                setLoadError(mError);
            }
        }
    }

    private class GetNotesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Notes>> {
        String mError = null;
        protected ArrayList<Notes> doInBackground(Void... parent) {
            ArrayList<Notes> result = new ArrayList<Notes>();
            try {
                result = myDataBase.getTicketNotes(mTicket.id());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                myDataBase.debugLog("Error caught" + e);
                mError = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Notes> result) {
            if (null != result) {
                Log.d("Result", result.toString());
                mNotes = result;
            } else {
                Log.d("SetNoteList","FALSE");
                mNotesListAdapter.setLoadError(mError);
            }

        }
    }

    private void updateDisplayedNotes(){
        ArrayList<Notes> newNotes = mNotes;
        if(newNotes != null) {
            mNotesListAdapter.setNoteList(newNotes);
        }
    }

    /*private class updateDisplayedNotes extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Notes>> {

        public ArrayList<Notes> newNotes = new ArrayList<Notes>();
        public updateDisplayedNotes(){
            super();
            Log.d(this.toString(), "Updating");
        }
        protected ArrayList<Notes> doInBackground(Void... parent) {

            Log.d(this.toString(), "Background Task");
            for (Notes note : mNotes) {
                Log.d(this.toString(),note.toString());
                if(note != null) {
                    Log.d(this.toString(), "Note Added");
                    newNotes.add(note);
                }
            }

            return newNotes;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Notes> newNotes)
        {
            if(newNotes != null) {
                mNotes.clear();
                mNotes.addAll(newNotes);
                mNotesListAdapter.setNoteList(mNotes);
            }
        }
    }*/


    void setLoadError(String error) {
        setContentView(R.layout.load_error_view);
        TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
        messageText.setText("Error loading ticket");
        String errorString = error != null ? error : "";
        TextView errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorText);
        errorText.setText(errorString);
        finish();
    }
}
```

### viewticketorder.xml (where note_list is)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ViewTicketOrderActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:text="@string/loadingTicket"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_transparent_bg"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/ticketID"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTicketID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/storeID"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStoreID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textStorePhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/category"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/note_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:divider="@drawable/ticket_item_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_transparent_bg">

    </ListView>


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="onClickAccept" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addUpdateButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickAddUpdate" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### notelist_item.xml (inflator)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/text_note_item"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#80FFFFFF"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/filler_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/text_item_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/big_text_item_size" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_weight=".70"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_note_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/filler_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/text_sub_item_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_note_by"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/filler_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/text_sub_item_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_note_by_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/filler_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/text_sub_item_color" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You create the adapter, but you never assign it to the ListView.

Comment: Thanks! I just assigned it within the UpdateDisplayedTicket() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to recommend you reorganize your code. Here are some general tips:

1) Keep your views like ListView in the Activity class. Don't try to inflate the view in your adapter class. So in your activity's onCreate() after setContentView() you should have something like:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

2) Next you need to get the data that will be shown in the listview and store it in a list. I didn't see in your code where the data comes from, but let's just say it comes from a database. You should create something like an ArrayList and store the data that you want to show in the ListView in the ArrayList

3) Next you need to create an adapter and pass the list of data into the adapter.

4) Once this has been done the ListView now has an adapter that will supply data to it. If you've done everything correctly then the system will eventually call getView() automatically and your code inside that should run and render the view.

Not an exact solution, but hopefully this explanation will help you figure it out.

Comment: The assignment was missing. I was using an existing Adapter class that was on a previous activity within the same app, and it *LOOKED* like the assignment was happening within the class. I know, now, this is not the case. I used this -> `ListView mNoteList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.note_list);mNoteList.setAdapter(mNotesListAdapter);` inside of the updateDisplayedTicket method and this worked. Thanks!

Comment: It is a mess, going into this code is like attempting to unravel cooked spaghetti. I am trying to clean it as I go. Thanks for the tips.